# VSE export edl or other markup format for editing?

Tags: export, video-sequence-editor, video

So I'm editing footage together in blender, and I would like to use other programs with it (ie. DaVinci Resolve) And those programs use an xml file to use the same footage at the same edit points. So is there some way to export my videos as an xml file?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: XML isn't a video-editor file format, its a markup language used for lots of things. Can edit your question to link to the file format specification you're referring to?